# Can the Join keyword be skipped?

Tags: sql

I found by accident that KhanAcademy accept omitting the join-keyword.
I think it is a bug, but could this work as a feature? A kind of "semi explicit join", to get a more compact syntax.
And a more intuitive way to move gradually from implicit to explicit join as you learn SQL.

[image: KhanAcademy]

### With self join

The "new" version with self join:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 a,
table2 b on a.id = b.id,
table2 c on a.id = c.id;
```

Implicit self join:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 a, table2 b, table2 c
where a.id = b.id
and a.id = c.id;
```

Explicit self join:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 a
join table2 b on a.id = b.id
join table2 c on a.id = c.id;
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Is there some reason why we can't remove join keyword? As in the question; "could this work"

Comment: No you can not remove it, because that's the way it's specified in the SQL standard.

Comment: There is something called a Natural Join. https://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/natural-join.php but that just omits the columns

Comment: Can't really figure out what are you asking. Can you edit your question?

Comment: SQL is a somewhat verbose language. *Could* simpler syntaxes be used? Yes. Are they likely to be introduced? *I* consider it unlikely.

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever, this was the answer I anticipated. The benefit of adding/removing this syntax is that it gives a more "gradual" and hopefully intuitive way of moving between implicit and explicit join syntax.

Comment: "*to move gradually between implicit and explicit join*" - just learn explicit joins right from the start. Don't bother learning the ancient, outdated and fragile implicit joins.

Comment: Tip of today: Stick to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: @Punnerud - explicit join syntax has existed for *a quarter of a century*. If people aren't using it, it's not because they need a "gradual" introduction.

Comment: @Punnerud - also, there's a whiff of [this xkcd](https://xkcd.com/927/)

Comment: I get an error on Oracle, but it works in sqlite3. Is it something wrong with this schema (https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) or the sqlite3 software?

Answer (score 0):

I found that this works in sqlite3 because the comma is interpreted as the join-keyword when it is between tables:

[image: join-operator]

Also wrote an article on this:
https://medium.com/@punnerud/sqlite3-bug-og-hidden-feature-6572e45a5adb